# /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: e#: not found

Tags: grub2, software-installation, dpkg

I was trying to install plank on Ubuntu 20.04 but then this message came up:

```
$ sudo apt install plank
[sudo] password for jatin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm10
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  bamfdaemon libbamf3-2 libplank-common libplank1
Suggested packages:
  libplank-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bamfdaemon libbamf3-2 libplank-common libplank1 plank
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 1 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/543 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,328 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 290111 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic (5.4.0-42.46) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: e#: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic package post-removal script subprocess r
eturned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is my grub file:

```
e# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

The same error occurred while I was trying to install software updates. I am also unable to update my GRUB file

Comment: Please remove the image and post the error message as text.

Comment: I have updated the post and also added my grub file.

Comment: Add the contents of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` instead of `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: @JatinKumar Remove `e` from line 1 of `/etc/default/grub` since that was supposed to be a commented line and run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: Thanks @Kulfy problem is resolved.